# How to add topic tree in the header file in order to access that every time MQTT is launched?

Tags: c++, mqtt

I am trying to add topic tree into the header file in order to access them every time I an launching the MQTT broker. I am using the forward slash "/"
to get into the sub branches such as:

Car/Bus/Temp/Fan

Here, Car is the root node and it branches to Bus which further branches to Temp and similarly Fan.

I am willing to create topic tree as stated above with multiple branches in C++ (QT creator) along with that it also updates the data whenever there is any change for that particular topic.

Also, as it creates the tree it prompts the user with error message if the topic entered to extract any data is incorrect.

Comment: If you are going to repost a question that has been put on hold (while waiting for it to get enough re-open votes), please delete the original question

Answer (score 0):

Firstly from the brokers point of view topics only exist at the point the message is published. The broker checks the topic in the incoming message against the subscription topic patterns<sup>*</sup> for each connected client (and any ACLs that may be in place) before forwarding the message to those clients that have a match.

There is no concept of pre-populating a broker with a list of topics that will be used.

As for the client, it doesn't need to store the topic tree it wants to publish messages on. It just needs to store the string that represents that topic as this is what any MQTT client library you will be using to publish messages will take as an input.

So you can just use `#define` to create macros that represent the topics as strings.

<sup>*</sup> clients subscribe to topic patterns, not specific topics, because they may contain wildcards

Comment: Thanks, how to give permissions access when we define a topic tree in the configuration file? also how to define them in the configuration files

Comment: can I define a topic tree in the config file? and when I say name/#  like the wildcard what should it return and how to execute parsing in this? thanks a lot

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here. But you don't implement access control on the client side that is all done in the broker (and well documented). I have not idea what you mean in your second question

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, I meant that can I define a topic tree with bunch of branches in the configuration file and if yes how? also when I enter the topic with certain name and wildcard will it return all the sub branches under it or only 1 of the sub branch, eg: Car has 2 branches temp1 and temp 2 so if I say car/# will it return both temp's ? thanks a lot

Comment: How you do string parsing is entirely up to you (and a totally separate question). But most languages will split a string to an array based on a given char.

Comment: Thanks, just a follow up question, if I want to define a topic tree with multiple levels how can I create that ? also I need to define in the configuration file, help is much appreciated!

Comment: That question doesn't make any sense

Comment: Sorry for that, I just mean that if I want to create a topic tree with multiple levels how can I do that like just A/B/C and keep going or is there a specific way? Thanks a lot

Comment: Asked and answered, topics are just strings

Comment: Thanks, is there a specific way we can do that and subscribe them in the config file? and string compare with the publish topic ? and if both are same it fetches the data and if not moves to the next

Comment: You keep asking the same question, but you never include enough information. Ask a new question, include a DETAILED description of everything (fully describe the problem you are trying to solve) . You keep switching between header files and config files, these are very different things.